# ArrayLists of various class types - generic method to find position of a key value in array

Tags: java, android, arraylist, dropdown, cursor-position

I have an Android app with multiple input forms with multiple drop downs.
For these forms, the user can enter and exit the record multiple times before they commit the record.
Hence if they chose something on a drop down, exited the record, came back in again - they would expect to see their last entry already preselected in the drop down.

Here is an example of one of the many class types that drives a drop down list:

```
public class SART implements Serializable
{
    private String Code;
    private String Description;

    public String getCode() {return Code;}
    public void setCode(String Code) {this.Code = Code;}

    public String getDescription() {return Description;}
    public void setDescription(String Description) {this.Description = Description;}
}
```

So I take a known value and look up its position in the array list that drives the drop down and select
this line in the drop down.
Here is an example of how I do it:

```
   int FindApplicationMethodPosition(ArrayList<SART> applicationMethods,String strExistingId)
    {
        int intSARTPosition = -1;

        if (strExistingId !=null)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <applicationMethods.size(); i++){
                if(applicationMethods.get(i).getCode().equals(strExistingId))
                {
                    intSARTPosition = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return intSARTPosition;
    }
```

I have about 30 different versions of this peppered through my code and I would like to try to call just one generic version.

```
    int FindPositionGeneric(Object array, String strExistingId)
    {
        int intRC = -1;
        intRC = IntStream.range(0, array.size())
                .filter(i -> array.get(i).getCode().equals(strExistingId))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(-1);

        return intRC;
    }
```

But of course the compiler does not like this at all.
Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

> But of course the compiler does not like this at all.

It doesn't know how to get the elements from `array`, nor how to get the `code` from an element in the array.

Pass in a `List<T>`, and a `Function<T, String>` to allow it to extract the code:

```
<T> int FindPositionGeneric(List<T> array, Function<T, String> codeFn, String strExistingId)
{
    int intRC = -1;
    intRC = IntStream.range(0, array.size())
            .filter(i -> codeFn.apply(array.get(i)).equals(strExistingId))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(-1);

    return intRC;
}
```

---

Note that this is inefficient for non-`RandomAccess` lists (e.g. `LinkedList`). An alternative solution would be a `ListIterator`-based loop:

```
ListIterator<T> it = array.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  int idx = it.nextIndex();
  String code = codeFn.apply(it.next());
  if (code.equals(strExistingId)) {
    return idx;
  }
}
return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the 30 versions of the class have the same `getCode()`, then create an interface (let it be `MyInterface`) and let all the classes implement this interface. Then update the method as follows:

```
 int FindPositionGeneric(List<MyInterface> list, String strExistingId)
    {

        int intRC = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                             .filter(i -> list.get(i).getCode().equals(strExistingId))
                             .findFirst()
                             .orElse(-1);

        return intRC;
    }
```

Also, since you have the `orElse`, no need to initialize `intRC` separately.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions. It's going to take me a few days to absorb these concepts.